# Remove lines containing numbers and/or symbols in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to remove all lines which contains numbers and/or symbols, for ex:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:04,080
random text 1

2
00:00:04,080 --> 00:00:04,920
random text 2

3
00:00:07,480 --> 00:00:08,800
random text 3
```

I did try with `^\s*([0-9 00*]+\s*)+$` using regex but it only removes lines 1, 5 and 9. resulting with

```
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:04,080
random text1

00:00:04,080 --> 00:00:04,920
random text2

00:00:07,480 --> 00:00:08,800
random text3
```

and it should be

```
random text 1

random text 2

random text 3
```

can this be done in notepad++? thanks in advance

Comment: 'random text1'  also contains a number (1)!

Comment: To remove lines without letters, starting with a digit: [^\d\PL*$\R?](https://regex101.com/r/tDNmIN/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to completely remove entire lines containing only an integer number or 2 time values, you may try using this pattern:

```
Find:   ^(?:\d+|\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3} --> \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3})$\R
Replace: (empty)
```

### Demo

This pattern will match:

- `^(?:` from the start of the line match either

  - `\d+` a positive integer
  - `|` OR
  - `\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3} --> \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d{3}` 2 time values
- `)$` end of the line
- `\R` also match ending newline (either `\n` or `\r\n`)

Comment: Congrats on hitting 500k!

Comment: This worked! i had a shorter regex written down years ago and it did the same but i've lost this. but this one you posted works flawlessly for me! thank you very much!